# Angular Communication between components data is not saved

Tags: angular, service, components

I'm trying to communicate between my 2 components. In first component I have list with items and I want to send one of this item to my second component to edit them. In first component I set data in my service and in second component I want read this data from service, data is coming but when I set this data to my array after leave ngOnInit method my array is clear.

It is my onClick for edit button in first component

```
editPurchasesInvoice(i : number) {
this.purchasesService.editPurchasesInvoice(this.purchasesInvoices[i].gpInvoiceitemsByGpInvoiceRecid);
this.router.navigate(['new'], {relativeTo: this.route});
}
```

Service methods

```
subject = new Subject<any>();

editPurchasesInvoice(invoiceItems: GpInvoiceitem[]) {
    this.subject.next({invoice: invoiceItems});
  }

  getEditedInvoice(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
```

it is my scond component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.purchaseService.getEditedInvoice().subscribe( data => {
      this.invoiceItems.push(data.invoice);
    });
  }
```

After leave ngOnInit method data is lost.

Comment: where are you trying to access it? What does "Leave ngonit" mean?

Comment: I want use my invoiceItems array in HTML file and display all of these items.
In ngOnInit method after push data into invoiceItems array it is not empty, everywhere else array is empty

Comment: There is too little information to reproduce. You should post your HTML structure and the relation between the two components. One possible solution could be to use a `BehaviorSubject` instead of a `Subject` inside your service

Comment: Do you have multiple *instances* of your Service class? How are you injecting them?

Comment: @PierreDuc I used BehaviorSubject and now it is working properly, data is displaying I also changed way to initialize invoiceItems to
this.invoiceItems = data.invoice;

Comment: @NicholasK I'm injecting my Service by constructor
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private purchaseService: purchasesService)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subscription to a `Subject` will only be received once new data is transmitted. A `BehaviourSubject` will emit the last pushed data on subscription. You can also use a `ReplaySubject`, which is basically the same, but where you can control the count of emits and you do not need to specify an initial value.

As stated in the comments, you should update your service to use either of these two, considering your data, I suggest a `ReplaySubject`:

```
readonly subject = new ReplaySubject<any>(1)

editPurchasesInvoice(invoiceItems: GpInvoiceitem[]) {
  this.subject.next({invoice: invoiceItems});
}

getEditedInvoice(): Observable<any> {
  return this.subject.asObservable();
}
```